# How to setup Continuous Delivery of a Polymer application on Azure?

Tags: polymer, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I admit I'm surely not expert on administrative things, but I have an ASP.NET Core 2 Web API that I correctly setup in Azure for continuous integration (it's almost automatic!) and it works perfectly.

Now I would like to do the same for a polymer client application, that I could already create as a project in VSTS (connection from Visual Studio Code working perfectly).

When I go to setup the continuous deployment, I'm stuck. I understand I have to do it manually, and I see a lot of templates, in VSTS, but I also understand that I would have to run a 'polymer build' command, and I don't know to setup the Polymer CLI in this environment...

Can anyone help at least a little bit?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: I'm really sorry, and at the same time I thank everyone: we are having big problems at the moment on other areas, so I will come to this later in the week... And I will make some good test, I hope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [Polymer CLI](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli) through **NPM** task: Command: `custom`; Command and arguments: `install -g polymer-cli`.

Comment: Thank you. But where do I have to install it? Do I have to create a custom virtual machine just for this? Sorry, but I'm puzzled...

Comment: @Andrea No, you just need to add NPM task to build definition, then choose custom in Command selectbox and specify `install -g polymer-cli` argument in Command and arguments input box.

Comment: Thank you very much, tonight I will give it a try!

Comment: @Andrea What's the result after trying it?

Comment: Sorry to come to this after so much time, but it's only in these Easter days that I could find some new time... Anyway, the NPM task looks running correctly, even if after that I cannot find the way to run the 'polymer build' command: I tried with a console, with a bash, with a powershell, but nothing... :-( The original question is solved, so I will mark this answer, but I still have to work! :-)